# Regexp alphabetical does not match

Tags: javascript, regex

What is wrong with this code? It `console.log` all keys not only `a-z`.

```js
const regExp = /[a-b]/;

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.key.match(regExp)) {
  console.log(e.key);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`[a-b]` means "from `a` to `b`" or, in this case equivalently, "`a` or `b`" (since they are the only two characters in that range.

You are getting also other matches because, for instance, `CapsLock` contains the character `a`.

Use `/^[ab]$/` instead (or `/^[a-z]$/`, if `b` was a typo).